# Can someone help me install wine?

Tags: wine

I'm a beginner in Linux and I'm trying to install wine useing

```
yum install wine
```

I'v tried every thing possible I'v installed epel packages and updated yum but it keeps giving me this

```
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.7.3)
Error: Package: wine-cms-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: liblcms.so.1
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libz.so.1
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.6.8)
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.6.15)
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: gnutls(x86-32)
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.6.23)
Error: Package: wine-pulseaudio-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: alsa-plugins-pulseaudio(x86-32)
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.6.2)
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.6.21)
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libglib-2.0.so.0
Error: Package: wine-alsa-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libasound.so.2(ALSA_0.9)
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libGLU.so.1
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.5.8)
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libGL.so.1
Error: Package: wine-ldap-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libldap_r-2.4.so.2
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libgstreamer-0.10.so.0
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libX11.so.6
Error: Package: wine-alsa-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libasound.so.2
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libXext.so.6
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libSM.so.6
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.5.7)
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libusb-0.1.so.4
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libgobject-2.0.so.0
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libICE.so.6
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libexif.so.12
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libgphoto2_port.so.0
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.6.14)
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libXrender(x86-32)
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.4.30)
Error: Package: wine-alsa-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libasound.so.2(ALSA_0.9.0rc4)
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: freetype(x86-32)
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libgstapp-0.10.so.0
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libgthread-2.0.so.0
Error: Package: wine-ldap-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: liblber-2.4.so.2
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libXcursor(x86-32)
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libgphoto2.so.2
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libgmodule-2.0.so.0
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.6.0)
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libxml2.so.2
Error: Package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: libgstbase-0.10.so.0
```

I could really use some help 
Thanks in advance

Comment: probably you are using fedora or redhat, such questions are not allowed here

Comment: For RHEL questions, try http://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

Try to `sudo apt-get install wine`. `Yum` (an acronym for Yellowdog Updater, Modified) is a package management utility for RPM compatible Linux operating Systems.

Comment: I'm using RHEL 6.3
bash: apt-get: command not found

Comment: @abdelrhman Hello, and Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. If this question is about Red Hat Enterprise Linux, then it is considered offtopic here on Ask Ubuntu and you might have better luck with it asking in http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Rhel questions are off topic here, try unix.stackexchange.com